# Why can't I place a campus on a plains tile as the Vietnamese?

Tags: civilization-6

I am playing as the Vietnamese. Overall, I'm trying to place a campus on a plains (1 food, 1 prod, and completely empty) within 3 tile from the city, but the game won't let me place it there.

If we look at the surrounding:

- Top side:         Farm - Woods
- Middle:  Mountain - (Plains) - Mountain.
- Bottom side:  Mountain - Mountain

[image]

Comment: Can the city support another district?

Comment: Yes the city can support another district!

Answer (score 4):

It's because of Vietnamese ability [Nine Dragon River Delta](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Vietnamese_(Civ6)#Nine_Dragon_River_Delta):

> All land specialty Districts can only be built on removable features